# Refactoring in Vim

Tags: vim, refactoring

Of course the fact that you can refactor on IDEs is priceless for many, I hardly ever do it when I am coding but I may try to do it when editing some one else's source. How do you accomplish such a trivial task across multiple files in Vim?

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/ecomba/vim-ruby-refactoring) for refactoring Ruby, but how about "any" language?

Comment: Refactoring is very language-specific. You need to look for specific add-ons for each language you're interested in. You'll presumably find add-ons for some and not for others. If there's one you want and can't find, then if you're feeling ambitious, you might try to write one, using an existing add-on for another similar language as a starting point.

Comment: VIM is designed around editing single files, and maybe files under a directory - not *projects*.  Many IDE-supported refactorings will impact files across the whole project (e.g. renaming a class).  I think it would be tricky to get this "right" with an editor like (g)VI(m), to the point where I think a company or a big project would have to take it on.  They'd basically have to parse each language to avoid doing simple string substitutions and become prone to errors (ctags gives *some* of this), as well as the corresponding project types (to know which files to edit).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think this is where things start to get tricky and trying to bend VIM to an IDE is not such as an elegant solution to using only one program to edit multiple languages. I truly do not want to give up on VIM due to some of the "advanced" features being available on IDEs.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - Some people just keep their code in a few (large, that may be) files. Avoids this problem altogether.

Comment: @ldigas: That would work around the problem.  But it is quite against recommended practices for some languages (e.g. Java).  Basically the code bending to fit the tool's needs, when it really should be the other way around.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - What you say IS true, but as much as that sounds bad, everyone "bends" code to fit their tool's needs.

Comment: +1ed to change your carma from Not Found to Conflict. Also, you might get some ideas on command line/vim refactoring from this post http://artemave.github.com/2013/02/14/refactoring-in-cmd-line-and-vim/

Comment: Who uses vim to write Java anyway.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: a huge ecosystem of Language Server Protocol servers have been created since I wrote this. They have brought great refactoring capabilities to Vim (and other editors). IMO they are still far from equaling the capabilities of a purpose-built IDE, but they're great. I prefer [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale), [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig), [null-ls](https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim), and [refactoring.nvim](https://github.com/ThePrimeagen/refactoring.nvim) to leverage these features (and [neovim](https://neovim.io/)). See other answers for more info!

---

I subscribe to the 'Vim is not an IDE' [philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). But there are times when there isn't an IDE. Here's what I do in those situations:

### :grep and :cdo commands

If the refactoring task has more to do with regular replacements I use a [:vimgrep](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimgrep)-like command to find files, [record a macro](http://viming.blogspot.com/2008/09/conditionally-applying-macro-recordings.html) to do the refactor or use :g and :s if its a no brainer, and use [:cdo](https://chrisarcand.com/vims-new-cdo-command/) (`:argdo`, `:bufdo`, etc) to execute the macro/command over all the matches.

Usually vim'll let me quickly modify a large number of files with very little effort. Honestly, I use this method more than any other.

The built-in vim commands might be slow/inconvenient for you. If you use git, you'll wanna use the excellent [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin and its `:Ggrep` command to only search files checked into git. I also like [vim-grepper](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-grepper) because it is search-tool-agnostic (supports ag, sift, ripgrep, etc). I often use [quickfix-reflector](https://github.com/stefandtw/quickfix-reflector.vim) to winnow down matches, and edit directly in the quickfix window.

### command line

When a simple `:grep` command doesn't cut it, I resort to the command line to more closely curate the list of files that I need to refactor. Save the list to a text file and use `:e` and a mashup of macro recordings to make the changes I need to make.

I find that the less rusty I keep my macro recording skills the more useful I find Vim for refactoring: feeling comfortable saving/restoring from registers, incrementing/decrementing register counter variables, cleaning/saving macro recordings to file for later use, etc.

Striving to understand my tools always makes the job easier: [git staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), CLI tools, and the language that I'm working with.

---

*Update*

Since writing this more videocasts for the methods I describe have been published on vimcasts.org (I encourage you to watch [ALL the Vimcasts!](http://vimcasts.org)). For refactoring watch these ones:

- [Substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)
- [Project wide search/replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/)
- [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)
- [Use :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/)

[Vimgolf](http://vimgolf.com) is also a great way to practice.

Comment: Refactoring is WAY more than pattern matching, that's why IDE's are needed to automate this in a safely manner. Obviously, you can do it manually, but considering the available options, and that most of the times it's safer to do it manually, why would you even consider any other option?

Comment: @CutbertoOcampo I agree with you to some extent: depending on myriad aspects of a project (structure, language(s), staff skills & resources, to name a few), there MAY be a great refactoring tool applicable to your problem. My answer applies to situations when that is not true, and you want to tackle the problem in Vim.

Comment: that's fine, I understand people may feel more comfortable doing thing using their long-time preferred tools, and that there're are some hacks that can perform really well, probably better than any IDE out there, but for an out-of-the-box solution I'd say an actual IDE would perform better for most users. I'd be thinking on a 80-20% kind of situation (even more, with the balance in favor of the IDE).

Comment: There is an ide for practically every language. Trying to refactoring with vim or regex sounds absolutely insane. Why would you even try?

Comment: @rolls to be potent enough to grab a random colleague's in-need machine with not-your-ide or whatever cfg you can only live with and leave a good impression around (not for "just impression" but for reputation and future position).

Comment: @bloody I don't actually understand what you just said?

Comment: @rolls At least one person did (1), but specially for you - take a raw linux server for example. You have only a shell and vim out there (ok and emacs if one prefers). How would you handle an unexpected help request in a corpo. from a colleague who has just taken over that machine (and that help involves renaming a variable;). I know, that's a zero-odds story but it doesn't have to be a raw server, just a system not tailored for your prefs. And it doesn't have to be renaming, just whatever non-trivial task. And still... the shell and vim is the bottom line always.

Comment: It is a bit different if your job title involves doing things like that. If you are stuck on the side of the road I'm sure you can fashion a tool out of sticks to jack a car up, doesn't mean its a good or effective tool for the job which is what I think everyone here is getting at.

Comment: @rolls Yes, you're example with a car is accurate, anyway it depends on a personal strategy. Btw. Note that you did not address me by `@` and I have just seen your reply after several weeks by accidental comments browsing. Remember about `@` while commenting non-post-author's comments :)

Answer (score 48):

### [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/overview)  (LSP)

The Language server protocol contains the feature for **smart renaming of symbols** across a project:

https://microsoft.github.io//language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-14/#textDocument_rename

For example following language server support this:

- [Clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/features.html#refactoring) for **C++**
- [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) for **C/C++/Objective-C**
- [Eclipse.jdt.ls](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) for **Java**
- [pyls](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server) (with rope) for **Python**
- [tsserver](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-%28tsserver%29) for **TypeScript**
- [Solargraph](https://solargraph.org/guides/language-server#supported-capabilities) for **Ruby**
- [gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls) official lsp for **Go** (alpha stage in Nov 2019)
- [texlab](https://texlab.netlify.com/) for **LaTeX**

You can find more language servers under https://langserver.org/.

#### Vim

A vim editor client is necessary to use them within vim. Following options exist:

1. [**LanguageClient-neovim**](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim) (requires rust)  suggests the mapping:

   ```
    nnoremap <silent> <F2> :call LanguageClient_textDocument_rename()<CR>
   ```
2. [**coc.nvim**](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) (requires node.js) suggests the mapping:

   ```
    " Remap for rename current word
    nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)
   ```
3. [**Ale**](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) has

   ```
    nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(ale_rename) :ALERename<Return>
   ```

   Ale does not define any keybindings. This has to be done by the user.
4. [**vim-lsp**](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp) provides following command

   ```
    :LspRename
   ```

   Similar to Ale no mapping is suggested. However, of course you can define one as following

   ```
    nmap <leader>r <plug>(lsp-rename)
   ```

   (`<leader>r` is to be replaced by your choice; I do not know one which most plugins agree on)
5. [**vim-lsc**](https://github.com/natebosch/vim-lsc) has a default mapping:

   ```
    'Rename': 'gR'
   ```

See also [**YouCompleteMe**](http://ycm-core.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#lsp-configuration) which facilitates LSPs as well.

#### [**Neovim**](https://neovim.io/)

Neovim has initial builtin support for lsp since [13.11.2019](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/00dc12c5d8454a2d3c6806710f63bbb446076e96)

See for common configurations of LSPs the project [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lsp) which suggests `<space>rn` as a mapping for `vim.lsp.buf.rename()`.

#### Other Refactorings

I do not know if there are plans for the LSP protocol to support more complex refactorings, such as changing class structure, adding parameters to methods/functions or moving a method to a different class. For a list of refactorings see https://refactoring.com/catalog/.

Comment: Unfortunately, the support for refactoring in the LSP is currently pretty weak compared to the state of art. https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/61

Comment: AFAIK that renaming for `coc-rename` only works on the current buffer. It didn't update the use of the exported name globally in the project (across files).

Answer (score 19):

#### Python

For the *python* language following plugins provide 'smart' renaming capabilities for vim:

- `jedi-vim` ([github](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim)) `<leader>r`
- `ropevim` ([github](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim)) `CTRL-c r r`
- `python-mode` ([github](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode)) `:h pymode-rope-refactoring`

Answer (score 13):

#### C-Family

1. Try the plugin [*Clighter*](https://github.com/bbchung/clighter) for rename-refactoring for the c-family. It is based on clang, but there are limitations and the plugin is marked as deprecated.

   Suggested mapping by *Clighter* is

   ```
    nmap <silent> <Leader>r :call clighter#Rename()<CR>
   ```

   Note, the successor plugin [*clighter8*](https://github.com/bbchung/clighter8) has removed the renaming functionality in the [commit 24927db42](https://github.com/bbchung/clighter8/commit/24927db42abada7662241e606ccd0569893d252d).
2. If you use neovim, you can take a look at the plugin [*clamp*](https://github.com/bbchung/Clamp). It suggests

   ```
    nmap <silent> <Leader>r :call ClampRename()<CR>
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhRefactor) for generic refactoring. It still requires many improvements. Sometime in the future I'll try to abandon ctags in favour of clang for C&C++ refactorings.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but I found it very handy: I use [ECLIM](http://eclim.org/) to connect VIM and Eclipse. Of course all my source code editing is done in VIM, but when it's time to refactor, one can take advantage of Eclipse's superior cababilities in this matter.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

#### Plugin [*YouCompleteMe* (YCM)](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) (20k stars on github)

http://ycm-core.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#the-refactorrename-new-name-subcommand

> `:h RefactorRename-new-name`
>
> In supported file types, this command attempts to perform a semantic
>   rename of the identifier under the cursor. This includes renaming
>   declarations, definitions and usages of the identifier, or any other
>   language-appropriate action. The specific behavior is defined by the
>   semantic engine in use.
>
> Similar to `FixIt`, this command applies automatic modifications to your
>   source files. Rename operations may involve changes to multiple files,
>   which may or may not be open in Vim buffers at the time. YouCompleteMe
>   handles all of this for you. The behavior is described in the
>   following section.
>
> Supported in filetypes: c, cpp, objc, objcpp, cuda, java, javascript,
>   typescript, rust, cs

By default there is no mapping.

Comment: So for now this works only for javascript, typescript and java?

Comment: In order to make this work across multiple files on the C-Family (using clangd) you need to add this to your .vimrc: let g:ycm_clangd_args = ['-cross-file-rename']

Answer (score 4):

Place cursor at name to refactor and type

<kbd>gd</kbd> (or <kbd>gD</kbd> if you're refactoring a global variable).

Then

<kbd>cgn</kbd> new_name <kbd>esc</kbd>

and

<kbd>.</kbd> one or more times to refactor next occurrence(s)

or

<kbd>:%norm .</kbd> to refactor all occurrences in the buffer at once.

Answer (score 3):

#### Plugin *Factorus*

There is another vim plugin dedicated for refactoring called *factorus* which is available on [github](https://github.com/apalmer1377/factorus).

Currently (2017-12), it supports the languages

- c,
- java, and
- python.

Answer (score 1):

I write a lot of C/C++ code in vim. The most common refactoring that I do is renaming variables, class names, etc. Usually, I use `:bufdo :%s/source/dest/g` to do a search/replace in files, which is almost the same as renaming provided by big IDE's.
However, in my case, I found that I usually rename similar entities, spelled in different cases (i.e CamelCase, snake_case, etc.), so I decided to write a small utility to help with this kind of "smart-case" search/replace, it is hosted [here](https://github.com/dkrikun/rename). It is a command-line utility, not a plugin for vim, I hope that you can find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Go

1. The tool [godoctor](http://gorefactor.org/) ([github](https://github.com/godoctor/godoctor)) supports several refactoring capabilities

> - Rename
> - Extract Function
> - Extract Local Variable
> - Toggle var ⇔ :=
> - Add Godoc stubs

There is a vim plugin https://github.com/godoctor/godoctor.vim which makes them available

> With cursor in thing to rename:
>
> ```
> :Rename <newname>
> ```
>
> Highlighting block to extract:
>
> ```
> :Refactor extract newfunc
> ```

2. [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go)

   - Precise type-safe renaming of identifiers with `:GoRename`.
3. Language server `gopls`

   - https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/status.md#rename

Answer (score 0):

For refactoring, if you're using [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) (and you should), you can then use [vim-qfreplace](https://github.com/thinca/vim-qfreplace) and make it extremely easy. Check this [video](http://vimeo.com/24700977) that demonstrates how it works. Once your workflow is set, you can make some mappings to optimize it (instead of typing most things like in the video).

Answer (score 0):

A combination of two plugins: [*vim-ripgrep*](https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep), to find across files and put the results in the quickfix window, and [*quickfix-reflector*](https://github.com/stefandtw/quickfix-reflector.vim) to save the changes right in the quickfix window and have it automatically save each change across the files.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the spacemacs version of emacs.  It is uses the same modes and most keystrokes as Vim but has many more add-on because of it's lisp nature.  If you want to program in C++ you just add the c++ layer and most of the IDE is just set up for you already.  For other interpreted languages like python or bash you do not need to leave spacemacs to use them.  They even have a way to run blocks of code directly within your text which works fantastic for literate programming or reproducible programming where the code and the data are in the same file.  Both done as text.

Spacemacs is much more heavy handed in it's initial load but the additional stuff you can do with it is worth the few seconds of startup cost.  One layer org-mode is worth checking it out.  It is the best outliner, programmer, day timer / todo list I have ever used.

Answer (score 0):

The CoC addon has (among other features) the ability to rename variables.

https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim

```
" Symbol renaming.
nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)
```