# How to change a variable name automatically across the project in VIM?

Tags: vim

In eclipse, if you change a variable name, eclipse will automatically change this variable's name in whole project.

Can vim do that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim is a *text editor*, not an *IDE*. Though it has some notion of a filetype's syntax, it does not fully parse nor understand the language's full syntax. Refactorings, even simple ones like *Rename identifier*, do require such full understanding (to be 100% correct).

There are [attempts at refactoring support in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781975/refactoring-in-vim), most language-specific, [some](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhRefactor) also generic. But I'd advise to keep using a real IDE for this (for its comfort, safety, and correctness), and instead use Vim only for simple, text-based replacements, using `:bufdo substitute/...` or macros, as described [here](http://rkulla.blogspot.de/2011/09/refactoring-with-vim-macros.html).

Comment: lhRefactor doesn't handle variable renaming at the moment. If some day I find time to investigate projects like this one (https://github.com/lukhnos/refactorial), I may attempt to provide an encapsulation for vim. Only C, C++, and perhaps Obj-C would be targeted. There is nothing planned right now.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

Because it is not an IDE and thus doesn't understand *anything* about your code, Vim only sees text where you see a variable name. It can't infer anything from the scope or whatever. Without the use of some external program, renaming a variable in Vim is usually done with a buffer-wide or project-wide search/replace.

Since you didn't tell us what language you are working with we can't tell you if there is a language-specific solution for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin -> [Clighter](https://github.com/bbchung/clighter), for c-family rename-refactoring. It's based on clang, but there are limitations. Still in development