# Capitalize all #define instances in multiple files

Tags: vim

I have a folder with a few header .h files and the .c application file. Many of the `#define`'s in the header file contain lower case names that I would like to replace with capitalized names. I would like it to search through all the files in the directory for an instance of that defined constant and replace it as well.

I could write a macro to do it in the header file alone by selecting all instances of the word, setting to uppercase and going through the file and forcing the rest to be uppercase (also not great because I'm assuming a maximum number of versions of the word in a file with however many `n.n.n.n.`'s I have)

```
*NveUn.n.n.n.n.
```

Desired output is....

Example BEFORE,

```
//test.h
#define test 0
```

```
//test.c
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n\r",test)
}
```

Example AFTER,

```
//test.h
#define TEST 0
```

```
//test.c
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n\r",TEST)
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I showed how I can do it in one file manually, I have no idea where to start for search and replacing that instance across multiple files.

Comment: have a look at `:h buffdo` there are also links to similar commands like `:ldo` or `tabdo` etc...

Comment: `:help :bufdo`, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the case for a refactoring plugin capability, otherwise will be very difficult to tell if a word found in other file places is actually the word we used in `#define`. This is just an assumption, but there are many videos on youtube about refactoring. Neovim now has [treesitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) support, which is a different way to parse code, instead of using regex for it.

I am just giving you these links related to the subject:

- [Refactoring in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781975/refactoring-in-vim)
- https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb7v1MZSrFc

You can grep all files creating a quickfix list and run something like:

```
:vimgrep '\v(.define |,)\zstest' **/*.c
:cfdo %s/\v( |,)\zstest/\U& 
:cfdo update
```

Explaining the above commands:

```
:vimgrep ........ grep a pattern 
**/*.c  ......... recursive search
\v .............. very magic (avoid many backslashes)
(.define |,) .... search for define + space or comma
\zs ............. start actual matching from this point
test ............ literal test

cfdo ............ Execute {cmd} in each file in the quickfix list.
cfdo update ..... write changes to all files
```

I hope this information could be any useful.